# partial cor (pcor.test) in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Can I use `pcor` (from `ppcor`) or actually put any correlation matrix I make in advance into the code of `ggpairs` (in the `upper =`) instead of `cor`?

I want to integrate within ggpairs a partial correlation matrix or the pcor.

```
library(GGally)
a <- as.numeric(1:10)
b <- as.numeric(a*a)
c <- as.numeric(a/b)
D <- as.factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A"))
abcd <- data.frame(a,b,c, D)

p <- ggpairs(abcd, columns = c("a", "b", "c"), title = "All Bivariate analysis", 
           upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor",   size = 6)),
           lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", alpha = 0.6, size = 0.1)),      
           mapping = aes(color = D))

for (i in 1:p$nrow) {
  for (j in 1:p$ncol) {
    p[i,j] <- p[i,j] + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey25", "slategrey", "grey85")) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("grey37", "slategrey", "grey75"))  
  }
}

d <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10 ),
             axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10),
             strip.text = element_text(size = 20))
d
```

I would like to use the fantastic `ggpairs` but whit partial correlation matrix.
 Is it possible? 
I guess I should do this in this part:

```
upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor",   size = 6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of `GGally::ggpairs` you can see that you can provide a function to `upper` which needs to produce a `ggplot`. When providing a function stub like this:

```
 upper = list(continuous = function(data, mapping) { print(list(data, mapping)) })
```

You will see that for each panel you get the whole `data.frame` and an `aes` mapping describing what should be on the x- and y-axis and which other aesthetics you may have set, for instance:

```
[[1]]
    a   b         c D
1   1   1 1.0000000 A
2   2   4 0.5000000 B
3   3   9 0.3333333 C
4   4  16 0.2500000 A
5   5  25 0.2000000 B
6   6  36 0.1666667 C
7   7  49 0.1428571 A
8   8  64 0.1250000 B
9   9  81 0.1111111 C
10 10 100 0.1000000 A

[[2]]
Aesthetic mapping: 
* `x`      -> `b`
* `y`      -> `a`
* `colour` -> `D`
```

Out of this information we need to

1. Calculate the `pcor`
2. Extract the relevant coefficients

This is a bit tricky, because we need to calculate a grouped `pcor` (one coefficient for each level of `colour -> D` + potentially other groupings which you may want to include later) and we would need to get the grouping structure from the mapping, which is also not that straight forward.

To make a long story short, the following stub shows you the direction and you can take it from there to further fine-tune the appearance of the upper plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
pcor_panel <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  ## remove x, y mapping
  grp_aes <- mapping[setdiff(names(mapping), c("x", "y"))]
  ## extract the columns to which x and y is mapped
  xy <- sapply(mapping[c("x", "y")], rlang::as_name)
  ## calculate pcor per group
  stats <- data %>%
    group_by(!!!unname(unclass(grp_aes))) %>%
    group_modify(function(dat, grp) {
      res <- pcor(dat)$estimate %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        setNames(names(dat)) ## needed b/c in pcor names are sometimes messed up
      res <- res %>%
        mutate(x = names(res)) %>%
        gather(y, pcor, -x)
      res %>%
        filter(x == xy[1], y == xy[2]) ## look only at the pcors of this panel
    }) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(x = 1, y = seq_along(y))
  ggplot(stats, aes(x, y, label = round(pcor, 3))) +
    geom_text(grp_aes) +
    ylim(range(stats$y) + c(-2, 2))
}

ggpairs(abcd, columns = c("a", "b", "c"), title = "All Bivariate analysis", 
        upper = list(continuous = pcor_panel),
        lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", alpha = 0.6, size = 0.1)),      
        mapping = aes(color = D))
```

[image]

Comment: @dalitmil: Thank you. It helped a lot (sorry it took me time to respond). But I noticed that in my original DATA, the axes in the different graphs are not in the same proportion. I work with results from a scale of 1-9. So in two graphs the X-axis is 2.5, 5, 7.5 and in the third axis, 2,4,6,8 - the same goes for the Y-axis of the diagonal density plots. Is there a way to change that in the code? To force the same bar Size of all plots?